# PHP display_errors=Off in php.ini settings issue

Tags: php

I have a custom php.ini file I created in my public_html directory. It works as I have checked the settings set are correct using phpinfo().

But the strange problem is the php.ini settings do not seem to apply to all sub_folders in the public_html directory?

Any ideas perhaps theres a setting needed in php.ini to apply to all subdirectories in public_html?

I found the answer myself you have to add the line into .htaccess file so it uses the custom php.ini file you created in public_html instead of having to copy php.ini file in every subdirectory you create.

Add this to .htaccess does the trick obviously replacing username

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/USERNAME/public_html/php.ini
```

Comment: perhaps you use for your new site a framework that sets errors=on?

Comment: Well I just copied my new index.php as the new hompage and the errors do not show so the script appears to be right? But when I revert back to my old homepage and type url of that new homepage file the errors appear to screen again?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, but you can disable overriding the `display_error` setting by using [`php_admin_flag`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) in your sites configuration. If it still happens then, you have set an [error handler](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler) which misbehaves.

Comment: Question changed. I noticed settings do work on pages inside public_html linked or unlinked. However does not apply to pages in directories in public_html ? Even on the live site the errors display in directories after public_html?

Comment: Settings are recursive, so if this is the case, either apache/vhost config does some overriding, or .htaccess files, but the latter cannot override a `php_admin_flag`, so one of the previous ones.

Comment: SetEnv PHPRC /home/USERNAME/public_html/php.ini  added to .htacess does the trick for subdirectories